# Linux kernel - How CPU subsystem(of CGROUPS) different from CPU scheduler?

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, cgroups, linux-namespaces

Linux kernel code [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/kernel/sched) provides, **CPU scheduler** that has multiple scheduling algorithms for scheduling the processes(including docker container processes).

---

A control group is a kernel construct, which allows for limiting access to, and accounting for, the usage of the physical resources of a host system, by a group of processes.

Control groups was originally implemented in Linux kernel in 2007.

This version 1 implementation was replaced by version 2 implementation in Linux kernel 4.5. Version 2 fixed some limitations associated with version 1 implementation.

Two of the six CGROUP subsystem in Linux kernel is **cpu subsystem** & **cpuset subsystem**.

**cpu subsystem** controls access to the system's CPU via scheduler

**cpuset subsystem** pins process belonging in CGROUPS to specific CPU cores or memory nodes.

---

How **CPU scheduler** different from **cpu subsystem**(of CGROUPS)? something to do with *default namespace* vs *multiple namespaces*?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to give a "short answer" without much oversimplification.  One could write a book on about "CPU scheduling", and another book on "Linux Control Groups".

Instead of "How [is the] CPU scheduler different from ... Cgroups?", a better question might be "How are Linux Cgroups different from Linux processes?"

> https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/ch01
>
> **How Control Groups Are Organized**
>
> Cgroups are organized hierarchically, like processes, and child
>   cgroups inherit some of the attributes of their parents. However,
>   there are differences between the two models.
>
> **The Linux Process Model**
>
> All processes on a Linux system are child processes of a common
>   parent: the init process, which is executed by the kernel at boot time
>   and starts other processes (which may in turn start child processes of
>   their own). Because all processes descend from a single parent, the
>   Linux process model is a single hierarchy, or tree.
>
> Additionally, every Linux process except init inherits the environment (such as the
>   PATH variable)[1] and certain other attributes (such as open file
>   descriptors) of its parent process.
>
> **The Cgroup Model**
>
> Cgroups are similar to processes in that:
>
> - they are hierarchical, and
> - child cgroups inherit certain attributes from their parent cgroup.
>
> The fundamental difference is that many different hierarchies of
>   cgroups can exist simultaneously on a system. If the Linux process
>   model is a single tree of processes, then the cgroup model is one or
>   more separate, unconnected trees of tasks (i.e. processes).
>
> Multiple separate hierarchies of cgroups are necessary because each hierarchy
>   is attached to one or more subsystems. A subsystem[2] represents a
>   single resource, such as CPU time or memory.

Returning back to your initial question:

- The Linux CPU scheduler allocates time to processes.
- The `CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED` group scheduler extension allows tasks to be
  grouped and divides CPU time fairly among such groups.

Look here for further information:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt
- https://opensource.com/article/19/2/fair-scheduling-linux

Comment: Does Linux process model exist anymore? or is it root CGROUP?

Comment: Of *COURSE* "the Linux process model" still exists!  It's worth noting, however, that CGroups are an enabling technology for Docker containers: https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/

Comment: Am unable to understand the meaning of root CGROUP... Can you please add this in your answer?

Comment: Please ask your new question in a new post.  Be sure to specify where you saw the term "root cgroup" - it would be helpful to know the context.